# Parameterized Procedure On different scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a requirement where there is parameterized procedure, say `USP_NAME`,
and if the user pass `''` (blank) in the parameter then different set of queries should run.

E.g.
When `Exec USP_NAME ''` then `Select A,B,C from tbl` should run.
When `Exec USP_NAME 'XYZ'` then `Select A,B,C,D from tbl` should run.

Both queries are written under same procedure.

```
create proc USP_NAME (@name varchar(100))     
as     
begin    
    if @name = ' '    
    begin    
        select A,B,C from tbl 
    end     
    if @name <> ' '    
    begin   
        select A,B,C,D from tbl    
    end   
end
```

I am trying this kind of stuff but somewhere the result is missing. running fine with less amount of data but when using the table which has 1million records then it is missing some records.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You had a look at [`IF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) already?

Comment: can't you set column `D` to `NULL` if you don't want to return the values for particular usernames?

Comment: The performance of this is going to randomly be horrible. This is a pattern known as multiple execution paths. You need a minimum of three procedures for this type of thing. One as a driver and a separate procedure for each result set. Otherwise the execution plans will sometimes be suboptimal because you are running different queries.

Comment: Now its working.. I am executing another procedure if name <> ''. Thanks @SeanLange

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve this using three procedures. Gail Shaw has a great article on this topic here. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

```
create procedure ABC
as
    set nocount on;
    select A,B,C from tbl

GO

create procedure ABCD
as
    set nocount on;
    select A,B,C,D from tbl

GO

create proc USP_NAME (@name varchar(100))     
as     
begin    
    if @name = ''    
        exec ABC
    else
        exec ABCD
end
```

--EDIT--

If you want to easily handle NULL or an empty string you can just reverse the logic a little bit and use an often overlooked way of dealing with NULL (> ''). This way if you receive an empty string OR a NULL it will execute ABC, otherwise if you receive any character it will execute ABCD.

```
create proc USP_NAME (@name varchar(100))     
as     
begin    
    if @name > ''    
        exec ABCD
    else
        exec ABC
end
```

Comment: what if the variable name contains null

Comment: will it not execute procedure ABCD then ?

Comment: @GuidoG the OP said they want it to execute one query if they "pass '' (blank)". They never said anything about NULL. You could make the argument that the parameter should be an optional one as well.

Comment: @GuidoG yes it would execute ABCD because it isn't an empty string which is what the OP stated they want to happen.

Comment: As the question is written, I agree. But I am guessing that the OP might have forgotten the NULL posibility for the name variable.

Comment: @Guido - The greater than empty string is often forgotten but is a great way of dealing with the issue as it doesn't need a function so the predicate remains SARGable.

Answer (score 0):

something as simple like this ?

```
create procedure dbo.USP_NAME (@name varchar(100)) as
begin
     set nocount on

     if ((@name is null) or (@name = '')) -- no need to trim empty spaces for a varchar
     begin
       select A, B, C from tbl
     end
     else if @name = 'XYZ'
     begin
       select A, B, C, D from tbl
     end
end
```

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2017 or better you can *finally* replace `ltrim(rtrim(...))` with `trim(...)`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning True, but he did not state on what  version of sql-server he is working

Comment: @AlwaysLearning but using trim on an empty string when checking for equality is not needed anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes very true, I edited my answer. Been in c# for to long where it does matter...